# can't connect to dnsmasq on local machine, port is open but connection refused

Tags: rhel, dnsmasq

I'm running Scientific Linux 6.3 and just updated the machine to dnsmasq-2.48-13.el6.x86_64.  The machine is on local ip 192.168.1.100.  I have a local caching DNS setup that was working until the update.

/etc/dnsmasq.conf configuration:

```
strict-order
listen-address=192.168.1.100
bind-interfaces
cache-size=5000
```

I confirmed that dnsmasq is running, the ports open and close as I start and stop dnsmasq.

```
$ netstat -nl # shows that the port was opened
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address        State
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.100:53        0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
udp        0      0 192.168.1.100:53        0.0.0.0:*
```

but trying to resolve fails

```
$ nslookup google.com 192.168.1.100
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

even trying to telnet fails

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.100 53
Trying 192.168.1.100...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.100: Connection refused
```

I don't seen anything in /var/log/messages related to dnsmasq.  Stopping iptables didn't help.  I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I just realized, I can connect to dnsmasq on the machine remotely.  But the local machine can't connect to itself using either 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.100.  Both refuse connections.

Comment: Should we take this to mean that you're only getting a "refused" when connecting to 192.168.1.100 from the same machine but connecting to 192.168.1.100 from a different machine does work?

Comment: That is correct.  Connecting to port 53 on 192.168.1.100 from a different machine on the network works fine.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall to see if that's blocking it?

Comment: I turned iptables off.  That was the only firewall running.  That didn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your additional info, you need to add this line to `dnsmasq.conf`, which my Slackware machine has in `/etc/`:

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

That's in addition to the other `listen-address` line.  You can configure more than one "listen-address". My guess is that you also need to comment out the "bind-interfaces" line, too, but that's just a guess.

You should also check what the `resolv-file` parameter value is. Does that file exist, and do its contents make sense?  You probably don't want something like:

```
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.conf
```

because that would make all the calls to `gethostbyname()` either skip using `dnsmasq`, or `dnsmasq` will try to use itself to resolve names, depending on what's in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Don't forget to restart `dnsmasq` after making changes.

Comment: That worked.  bind-interfaces DID need to be commented out also...  Thanks.